# Vert.x metrics from multiple httpClient

Tags: jvm, vert.x

I have multiple `httpClient` instances in one app. I want to collect metrics by each `httpClient` with specific label or name. Is it possible with `vert.x`? I saw in documentation block of collecting `httpClient` metrics and I want to enrich each metric with specification for client.

Answer (score 2):

You can [provide a metrics name](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpClientOptions.html#setMetricsName-java.lang.String-) when creating the client:

```
HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions().setMetricsName("foo");
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But this solution doesn`t work for me, because when i added specific metricsName i still got metrics with name like default (vertx_http_client_active_connections and etc)

Comment: I got smth like what i need with config param labels = setOf(Label.REMOTE) in MicrometerMetricsOptions, but specific prefix or suffix would be more preferred

Comment: Ah, perhaps that only works with Vert.x Dropwizard Metrics

Comment: I filed this: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-dropwizard-metrics/issues/106